# How to add a shapefile in eCognition?

Tags: shapefile, import, ecognition

I added the shapefile from thematic layers but I am not able to view the imported shapefile in the project window on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the **View** menu, choose **Vector Layer Mixing** and you will see a window that lists all the Thematic Layers. Here you can select which ones you want displayed.

[image: Vector Layer Mixing window]

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that you cannot view a shapefile in eCognition Essentials.  It's not made for that.